# Beamer frametitle separator

Tags: beamer

I'm wondering why this minimal example is not doing great when there is no framesubtitle content...

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{% 
     \nointerlineskip%

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3.75ex,left]{frametitle}% 
         \hspace*{2ex}\strut{\insertframetitle}\strut
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\@empty%
      \else
      {%\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}%
       \usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}%
      \strut{ - \insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
      \fi
  \vskip-1ex
\end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}{frame subtitle}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `\@empty`, use `\empty` in the conditional `\ifx`:

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{% 
     \nointerlineskip%

\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3.75ex,left]{frametitle}% 
         \hspace*{2ex}\strut{\insertframetitle}\strut
      \ifx\insertframesubtitle\empty%
      \else
      {%\usebeamerfont{framesubtitle}%
       \usebeamercolor[fg]{framesubtitle}%
      \strut{ - \insertframesubtitle}\strut\par}%
      \fi
  \vskip-1ex
\end{beamercolorbox}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}{frame subtitle}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame Title}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

By the way, when using commands containing the `@` character in a `.tex` file, you should use `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` (in this case, however, there will be no need since your definition won't contain this character); moreover, using `\@empty` and adding `\makeatletter`, `\makeatother` won't produce the desired result either; I just wanted to mention that using `@` in control sequence names requires the precaution of `\makeatleter`, `\makeatother`.